# Creating Python Toolbox (*.pyt)?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-toolbox

I would like to create a new shapefile based on input.

My input is DATE parameter. This is my code for input parameter:

```
param = arcpy.Parameter(
displayName="TARIKH",
name="date_feature",
datatype="Date",
parameterType="Required",
direction="Input")
```

and then the value in this parameter will be analysed using this code:

```
  out_path = "C:/Last"
geometry_type = "POLYGON"
out_name = #DATEINPUT
result = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path, out_name,geometry_type)
```

The main point is, I don't know how to input all this code into toolbox code.

#

This is the full code which I don't know where to put and what to insert into an .pyt toolbox

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Tool]


class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Tool"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):

        """Define parameter definitions"""
        param = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="TARIKH",
        name="date_feature",
        datatype="Date",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
        #date_features.filter.list = ["Point","Polyline","Polygon"]

        #params = [date_features]
        return 

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""

        self.param[0] = date_feature

        print "Your new shapefile sucessfull created"
        out_path = "C:/Last"
        geometry_type = "POLYGON"
        out_name = date_features
        result = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path, out_name,geometry_type)

        return 

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        return
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Would you be able to use the **edit** button beneath your question to revise it with a few more details, please?  Are you trying to write a Python toolbox (*.pyt) or something else? How does a date input relate to creating a shapefile?

Comment: yes , im try to write python toolbox, i just want to the user just insert a date for creating a newshapefile and the name of the shapefile is based on date insert. for example 14/08/2015 the shapefile name will be 14082015.shp

Comment: Please include those additional details into your question.  What happens when you try to open and run your tool as it stands?  To help I think we will need to see the code for a whole *.pyt file (Python toolbox) from you - just make sure that it defines only the one tool that you need help with in it.

Comment: the input working well, but idk where the variable go.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is move what you had in updateParameters down to execute. What would otherwise be a standalone python script goes there. Fixed some other issues in your code as well, this should be functional (keep everything before getParameterInfo like you had it):

```
    def getParameterInfo(self):
        param = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="TARIKH",
        name="date_feature",
        datatype="Date",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

        params = [param] #makes a list of your parameters

        return params #returns your list for future use

    def isLicensed(self):
        return True
    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        return 
    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        return

    def execute(self, params, messages): #notice that params is listed

        date_feature = params[0].valueAsText #gets the first value from your list as text
        out_name = date_feature.replace("/", "") #removes slash formating from string
        out_path = "C:/Last"
        geometry_type = "POLYGON"

        arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path, out_name, geometry_type)
        arcpy.AddMessage("Your new shapefile sucessfully created")

        return
```

Other resources for learning .pyt:
ESRI has a free [webinar](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&courseID=2523) and [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Defining_parameters_in_a_Python_toolbox/001500000028000000/) that you may find helpful.